# How do you extract the boot.img from a Samsung G4?

Tags: adb, samsung-galaxy-s-3, boot, kernel

I don't imagine the ADB command is able to access that sector of the device but for the record, when I connect, I can see the device but

```
C:\Users\Brad2\Downloads\adbUnzip2Cdrive\adb>adb kill-server

C:\Users\Brad2\Downloads\adbUnzip2Cdrive\adb>adb devices
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *

List of devices attached

51cfe754        offline
```

I can connect to the device with Odin in download mode, but I do not see a 'pull' or extract feature on Odin, only push.

What is the trick to extracting the boot files from the device?
All drivers and SDKs are installed and using the current ADB.

Comment: Is your device on Android 4.2 or greater? Make sure you have ADB 1.0.31, (as much as possible) using the cable provided with your device, switch ports if necessary.

Comment: I am running 4.4.2 and Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.26

Answer (score 0):

Getting the proper ADB version and also using Linux instead of Windows *and* screwing with the USB debug feature until a proper RSA key exchange finally occurred. The combination of the 3 corrected the issue.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I would like to use the same steps. Thanks! I can't even find what adb command I would run to get the boot.img from the phone.